# highlight navigation dots while scrolling down on page

Tags: jquery

Will try to explain this :)
I have a navigation that scrolls to different anchors on the page. When the user is on one of the anchors the navigation shows an active link.

Now i think that one nice effect would be if the user,  lets say is on the top of the page, clicks on the link that moves us to the bottom on the page and while its scrolling down every link in between will be highlight when the scroll pass by. Like a stoplight.

I have this Jquery for the moment, but its only add/remove class on the clicked link.
Any ideas on how I should go on ?

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });

        $('.navigation ul li a').click(function () {
        $('.navigation ul li a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
    });   
});
```

I also created an [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hu5dC/1/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT : Modified the code for better performance.**

I made a JSFiddle that work here what I added

```
var parPosition = [];
        $('.par').each(function() {
            parPosition.push($(this).offset().top);
        });

        $(document).on('scroll', function() {
            var position = $(document).scrollTop(),
                index;

            for (var i=0; i<parPosition.length; i++) {
                if (position <= parPosition[i]) {
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            $('.navigation ul li a')
               .removeClass('active')
               .eq(index)
               .addClass('active');
        });
```

As you can see, I added the class "par" to all paragraph. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dfuF9/1/)

Comment: Wow. Thank you. damn genius will inspect the code and learn from you :)

Comment: No problem. Hope it will be usefull :)