# One page scroll active links menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need help to make the links active when you reach a certain section on scroll.

Right now the menu works when I click the specific links with a smooth transition.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4rrv7dpe/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){   
    menuTransition();
    transitionTop();
    sectionScroll();
});

function menuTransition() {
    jQuery(document).on('click', '#main-header a', function(event){
        var targetSection = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        var scrTo = jQuery(targetSection).offset().top;
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: scrTo
        }, 1000)
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}

// Smooth transition to the top of the page
function transitionTop() {
    jQuery("a[href=#page-top]").on("click", function (e) {
      //alert("top")
      jQuery('html, body').animate({
         'scrollTop': 0
     }, 1000)
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}

function sectionScroll() {

}
```

I tried creating the function sectionScroll() for this part.

Comment: so the `function sectionScroll() {}` needs to handle this functionality?

Comment: What about this discussion and this jsfiddle 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17686828/highlight-navigation-dots-while-scrolling-down-on-page#17687215
http://jsfiddle.net/dfuF9/1/